# Is it acceptable to ask about a list of definitions in text or HTML format for a specific topic?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

I am looking for definitions of specific items (in this case, descriptions for barcode identifiers, but I am asking in general).

Let's say that I have a PDF-based description of a few specific items (could be enumerations etc). I would like to know if this is available in text or HTML format.

Would this be acceptable to ask on Stack Overflow, given an appropriate tag and a link to the PDF version, or would there be a better Stack Exchange site to ask on? The topic is technical, and the tag exists.

I know that Stack Overflow is not generally to be used for web links for various things.

Comment: Would question and answer(s) be self-contained or depend on links to external resources?

Comment: chekc if the pdf ios text or images, text can be copied images have to be scanned by ocr and tobe on topic no it isn't allowed to aks such a question

Comment: It is also not used for questions which are not programming problems. This does not sound like a programming problem at all.

Answer (score 11):

> Let's say that I have a PDF-based description of a few specific items (could be enumerations etc). I would like to know if this is available in text/html format.

You would be asking for an off-site resource. A link to a document in a specific format.

That would not be on-topic here, nor in any other site in the network I could think of.

> The topic is technical, and the tag exists.

Neither of these things is particularly relevant. It's possible to formulate off-topic questions about programming, and about any possible tag.

Comment: I will not ask the question, explanation given. However I am surprised that I am downvoted even for asking politely what is acceptable. If you can't even *ask* about the rules (and not break them), and are still punished, certainly it will scare some people away.

Comment: I'm sorry your question in meta was downvoted. Maybe some users felt that your question did not show an appropriate amount of research. E.g. linking to the help center pages that deal with this kind of thing, and explaining what exactly you felt was unclear in those articles. In any case, do not worry about votes here. Votes in meta will not affect your reputation or your account in any way. The important thing is that you got an answer to your question so you better understand the site rules.

Comment: @MyICQ in what way are downvotes (particularly on meta) punishment. Meta votes have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, I have learned that, but was in fact not aware about it.

Comment: Downvotes on meta are also frequently used to simply indicate disagreement with whatever viewpoint is proposed. So I suspect most of those downvotes are from people who think your question implies that you think it *should* be acceptable (or otherwise you wouldn't ask it), and who disagree.